# Users Receiving Error When Creating a List in SharePoint

Tags: list

Some of my users are getting a strange error I'm not able to solve. I've done several searches on this topic and found nothing even remotely like it.

Here's the what is happening, a user (who has Full Control rights on his SharePoint 2013 site) gets the following error when he attempts to create a new list on their sites:

---

**error_pagetitle
An error occurred while getting the items.
[AgrumentNull_Generic]
Agruments:
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See Link  Parameter name: s**

---

When I follow the same steps, I get the list templates that I expect to see and can create lists. I tested this by allowing a user who was getting this error to login to SharePoint with his credentials on my computer. He got the error again. So it is not a problem on the users computer. It doesn't seem to be a permissions issue either, as I've tested several scenarios along that line.

Steps to reproduce this error:

1. On the affected site, click on the "All Site Content" link.
2. On the all site content page, click on the "Create" link.
3. Error message displays.

I checked the ULS logs and found nothing helpful. Can anyone give me advice on how to resolve this error? Anything would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The fix for this was fairly simple. I gave the user full control of the site collection over his site and that allowed him to see all the list templates. I can remove his access to the site collection after he's created the calendars he needs. Probably not the best answer, but it is allowing the user to get work done.

So it was a permissions issue.